# Prove that $\int f(x)g(y) \,d(\mu \times \nu) = [\int f\, d\mu ][\int g \,d\nu]$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

I got stuck on this problem to figure out how to calculate the integral on left-handed side, because we can't use Tonelli-Fubini theorem for this problem (lack of $\sigma$-finite condition). Hope someone can help me or give some hint to solve it.

I'm thinking about building two simple function sequences $\{f_n\}$ and $\{g_n\}$ which converge to $f$ and $g$ correspondingly, but can't come to the conclusion. Thanks so much.

> > Let $(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$ and $(Y, \mathcal{N}, v)$ be arbitrary measure spaces. If $f \in L^1(\mu)$ and $g \in L^1(v)$, prove that $h(x, y) = f(x)g(y) \in L^1(\mu \times v)$ and $\int h \, d(\mu \times v) = [\int f\,d\mu][\int g\,dv]$.

Comment: I think you're on the right track with simple functions because the sets on which $f$ and $g$ are finite are always $\sigma$-finite (since they are integrable). I think the product form of $h$ lets you basically fall right into the $\sigma$-finite setting. Show that the integrals work for finite measure simple functions and extend from there. There are details that need to be worked out though.

Comment: What do you mean by $\mu \times \nu$ if the spaces are not $\sigma$-finite?

Comment: @nullUser: Hm, this problem is exercise 51, chapter 2 from Folland, and he states very clearly that those spaces not need to be $\sigma$-finite. When reading this book, he states that $\sigma$-finite condition helps to define "uniquely" measure $\mu \times v$ such that $\mu \times v(A \times B) = \mu(A) v(B)$, but I think we can still define product measure on arbitrary spaces. Is it true?

Comment: Ahh, the wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_measure provides the answer in the affirmative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track with using simple functions. Let's just reduce to the case where $f\geq 0, g\geq 0$ (this is a typical argument, assuming it holds for this special case, proving it holds for $f=f^+-f^-$ and then $f=\text{Re} f+i\text{Im} f$).

Let $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}},(g_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of simple functions converging monotonically pointwise to $f,g$ respectively. Then define $F_n:X\times Y\to[0,\infty]$ by $F_n(x,y)=f_n(x)$ and similarly for $G_n(x,y)=g_n(y)$. It is very easy to show that this is $\mu\times \nu$ measurable. Moreover, $F_nG_n$ converges pointwise monotonically to $h$.

Now the proof: Prove that $$\int F_n G_n d(\mu\times\nu)=(\int F_nd\mu)\cdot(\int G_nd\nu)$$for fixed $n$. This is relatively simple:
Let $$F_n=\sum_{i=1}^k a_i\chi_{A_i\times Y}, G_n=\sum_{j=1}^m b_j\chi_{X\times B_j}$$where $f_n=\sum_i a_i\chi_{A_i},g_n=\sum_j b_j\chi_{B_j}$ and for $a_i,b_j\in[0,\infty]$, $A_i\in \mathcal{M},B_j\in\mathcal{N}$. Then it is easy to see that $$F_nG_n(x,y)=\sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{j=1}^m a_ib_j\chi_{A_i\times B_j}$$by mutliplying these functions. Then \begin{align*}\int F_nG_nd(\mu\times\nu)=\sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{j=1}^m a_ib_j\mu\times\nu(A_i\times B_j)=\sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{j=1}^m a_ib_j\mu(A_i)\nu(B_j)\\=(\sum_{i=1}^k a_i\mu(A_i))\cdot(\sum_{j=1}^m b_j\nu(B_j)=(\int F_nd\mu)\cdot (\int G_nd\nu)\end{align*}Then the result follows by the Monotone Convergence Theorem and the fact that the limit of the product is the product of the limits.

Comment: Thanks so much. So the condition for $\sigma$-finite is really unnecessary here, right!

Comment: Sorry for the late reply: No you don't, as the issue here is not so much about Fubini-Tonelli, more just general integration against product measures. $\sigma$-finiteness for products is only important for Fubini-Tonelli. Here we only need that the product measure has the property that $\mu\times\nu(A\times B)=\mu(A)\nu(B)$ for $A\in M, B\in N$. See https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/measure_theory/measure_notes_ch5.pdf